# VBA on how to delete rows that do not contain text

Tags: excel, contains, delete-row, vba

I have a column (H) that I need to search if it contains 1 of 4 words. If it does not contain 1 of those 4 words I need the row to either be hidden or deleted. What is the best way to go about acheiving this?

Comment: I forgot to mention that there are other words in column H along with the four words i am interested in. So the code needs to be able to search for rows containing one of those 4

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following to a module and running.  I have assumed column H has a header so the range begins on row 2.

```
Public Sub Test()
Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("H2:H7")

For Each row In rng.Rows
For Each cell In row.Cells

Select Case cell.Value
Case "Red", "Blue", "Green", "White"
'Do nothing
Case Else
row.Hidden = True
End Select

Next cell
Next row
End Sub
```

Comment: Go with this answer as if you delete a row it will stuff up  the for each and you would have to do a workaround like clear contents then sort to move the blanks to the bottom..

Comment: Okay, this code does not work, when I run it, it deletes or hides everything. I forgot to mention there are other words in these columns along with these 4 words.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you prefer to delete:

```
lastRow = Range("H65000").End(xlUp).Row
For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
Select Case Cells(i, 8).Value
    Case "Red", "Blue", "Green", "White"
        'Do nothing
    Case Else
        Cells(i, 8).EntireRow.Delete
End Select
Next i
```